# How do I display last five nodes, with the latest at the bottom using views?

Tags: views

I am creating a view which lists node titles for a specific node type. I want to display the 5 latest nodes with the latest at the bottom of the list.

If I sort using the post date criteria in an ascending manner, then the earliest 5 posts are shown. If I use descending, then the latest 5 are shown, but the the latest is at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that Views does not support this. It's a somewhat frequent request for listing comments as well, but you can't add sorting after filtering/paging.

The easiest way is to change the view template to output the rows in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use hook_views_pre_render() to reverse the order of the rows before they get to the template but after sorting/paging. That way you can keep php logic out of your template files.